# Deprecated: setcookie(): Passing null to parameter #5 ($domain) of type string is deprecated in woedpress and php version 8.2

Tags: php

I have a function and it's getting

> Deprecated: setcookie(): Passing null to parameter #5 ($domain) of
> type string is deprecated on php version 8.2.

That function is below...

```
function qtranxf_setcookie_language($lang, $cookie_name, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain = NULL, $secure = false){
    qtranxf_dbg_log('qtranxf_setcookie_language: lang='.$lang.'; cookie_name='.$cookie_name.'; cookie_path='.$cookie_path);
    setcookie($cookie_name, $lang, time()+31536000, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain, $secure);//one year
    //two weeks 1209600
}
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Either resolve the problem as proposed in the deprecation notice (which is a notice, not any error!) on your own, or search for an update of the plugin you are using

Answer (score 1):

As the warning message indicates:
You just hve to set $domain to "" instead of null:

```
function qtranxf_setcookie_language($lang, $cookie_name, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain = '', $secure = false){
```

Comment: Sorry it is only work on, if user login. if user not have login showing same deprecated message.

Comment: You simply have to take care that the parameter $cookie_domain is not null. It can be an empty string but it must not be null. So change the method signature with setting the default of $cookie_domain to '', that's all